# Difficult date calculation in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-11', periods=5, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'status': ['active', 'active', 'finished', 'finished', 'active'] })
```

And I need to create 2 new columns in this DataFrame:

1. New1 = amount of days from "Date" column until today for status 'active'
2. New2 = amount of days from "Date" column until today for status 'finished'

Below sample result:

[image]

Comment: How looks new columns by sample data?

Comment: I added sample results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side with today by [`Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) and [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html), convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and assign new columns by condition in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 
                    'status': ['active', 'active', 'finished', 'finished', 'active'] }) 

days = df['Date'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d')).dt.days

df['New1'] = days.where(df['status'].eq('active'))
df['New2'] = days.where(df['status'].eq('finished'))
print (df)
        Date    status  New1  New2
0 2020-12-01    active  13.0   NaN
1 2020-12-02    active  12.0   NaN
2 2020-12-03  finished   NaN  11.0
3 2020-12-04  finished   NaN  10.0
4 2020-12-05    active   9.0   NaN
```

Comment: I have error like below after your code: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: @rumor154 - Are values in `Date` column datetimes? It seems not, so use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` before `days = df['Date'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d')).dt.days`